# How to turn off all tomcat log rotation

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat8

I want to manage log rotation on my server using logrotate, however Tomcat performs its own log rotation which interacts badly with logrotate, and I can't find a way to turn it off. My Tomcat instance currently produces 5 types of log:

- catalina.2018-01-17.log
- mysite_access.2018-01-17.log
- localhost.2018-01-17.log
- host-manager.2018-01-17.log
- manager.2018-01-17.log

After some googling I have discovered that I can disable rotation for the 'mysite' logs by adding `rotatable="false"` into the appropriate `<Value>` element in server.xml, but none of the other logs have corresponding `<Value>` elements.

The logs seems to be configured by the logging.properties file, but I can't find a 'turn rotation off' option for this file. Can anyone help? I'm using Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Same question on serverfault for reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/892824/how-to-turn-off-all-tomcat-log-rotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The logs seems to be configured by the logging.properties file, but I can't find a 'turn rotation off' option for this file

You can try using a different log handler and configure it to avoid rotation

Your properties file probably holds this configuration (if you haven't changed the default settings)

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = DEBUG
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
```

You can change it to a [`java.util.logging.FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) and disable the size limit for a rotation

```
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = DEBUG
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%g.log 

# set below limit to 0 !!
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 0
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/data_processing_bdd/src/rdp_logging_config.html)

> java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit
>
> The maximum size of the file, in bytes. If this is 0, there is no limit. The default is 1000000 (which is 1 MB). Logs larger than 1MB roll over to the next log file

Since there is no limit, a file rotation will never occur.

Answer (score 2):

There is option available in [org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) to turn of the `rotatable` functionality. You can directly add following param to disable to log rotation:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.rotatable = false
```